# How do you scrape an image from a website using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, web-scraping

Hi I'm trying to do a simple task of getting the img src url from a website but I can't seem to do it, I've tried various flutter packages and now I've reverted back to vanilla Flutter. This is my code:

```
onPressed: () async {
                http.Response response = await http.get('https://tiktok.com/@$enteredUsername');
                dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
                final elements = document.getElementsByClassName('jsx-581822467');
                print(elements);
              },
```

I'm simply trying to get the image URL from this website (tiktok.com):

[image]

I've looked into the source code and it says the class name is 'jsx-581822467', but if I try to use that in the code it returns with a blank list.

[image]

How can I just simply get the URL of this profile picture? And the other elements with the 'jsx' prefix as their class names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured out what your problem is. The inspector of the web browser displays the HTML on a TikTok profile page. However, this is only generated with JavaScript once the page is loaded. If we download the content via `http.get()`, we get the raw HTML before JavaScript can do any changes.

- Write `http.get(),` in front of your URL or right-click on the website and click on **View Page Source**. Now the HTML will be displayed in the same way as your app gets it.
- Search for `avatar-wrapper round`. You won't be able to find it, because the  tag from the profile picture doesn't exist here yet.
- Fortunately, the URL of the profile picture is already included in other places. Search for `<meta property="og:image" content="`. You will find only one hit and after the hit the URL of the profile picture starts directly.

Therefore, in my opinion, the easiest way to get the URL is:

1. download HTML.
2. remove all text up to `<meta property="og:image" content="`.
3. all following characters up to the next `"` are the URL we are looking for.

Here I have inserted my code, which worked fine for me:

```dart
Future<String> getProfileImageUrl(String username) async {
  // Download the content of the site
  http.Response response = await http.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@$username");
  String html = response.body;

  // The html contains the following string exactly one time.
  // After this specific string the url of the profile picture starts. 
  String needle = '<meta property="og:image" content="';
  int index = html.indexOf(needle);

  // The result of indexOf() equals -1 if the needle didn't occurred in the html.
  // In that case the received username may be invalid.
  if (index == -1)
    return null;

  // Remove all characters up to the start of the text snippet that we want.
  html = html.substring(html.indexOf(needle) + needle.length);

  // return all chars until the first occurrence of '"'
  return html.substring(0, html.indexOf('"'));
}
```

I hope that I could help you with my explanation.

---

Edit 1: **General approach**

1. view page source to view HTML of the page
2. search for the desired substring.
3. Select the previous 10 to 15 characters and see how often this string occurs before.
4. If it occurs more than once, you must call `html = html.substring(html.indexOf(needle) + needle.length);` accordingly often repeatedly.
5. reload the page and check if it still works.
6. now you have found your needle string.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Could you just explain for me what the Integer 'index' means and how you obtained it, and why you need to obtain it? Thanks.

Comment: The index specifies the position where `<meta property="og:image" content="` first appears in html. My approach is to cut out the desired URL from the HTML (point 2 on the list in my answer). We need the index here to be able to cut away all text before the URL.
I have expanded my answer to explain how you can handle other websites.